# Robust estimator of mean for skewed data

Tags: skewness, robust, mean, heavy-tailed

For heavy-tailed symmetric data, a trimmed mean or other robust estimator of the mean could be a better estimator of the mean than the sample mean. The trimmed mean will be biased for a skewed distribution. What is a robust estimator of the mean that is not biased for a skewed distribution?

Comment: a trimmed mean is not an estimator of the mean (though they may coincide in some situations). Until you clear out this ambiguity (what do you *really* want to estimate, a measure of location perhaps) you question cannot be answered.

Comment: @user603 given the restriction to symmetric distributions in the first sentence of the question, a symmetrically trimmed mean would be a reasonable estimator for the population mean in a very wide range of such circumstances (assuming the mean exists).

Comment: Here is an idea I had. One way to robustly estimate the mean for a symmmetric distribution is to fit a Student t distribution with a small degrees-of-freedom parameter, say 5. Maybe you can estimate the mean for an asymmetric distribution by fitting a skewed Student t distribution.

Comment: Let's not conflate "estimator" with "unbiased estimator." A trimmed mean may be biased (although as Glen_b points out, it is not biased for symmetric distributions), but that property does not imply it fails to be an estimator of the mean. Fortranner: although fitting a Student t is a creative idea, likely it is not a robust method. That ought to be extremely sensitive to departures between the true distribution and the fitted one. BTW, your question is unclear. By "skewed distribution" do you mean the family of *all* skewed distributions or do you have a particular family in mind?